# Display header elsewhere

Tags: fullcalendar, yii2

I would like to sperate fullcalendar body from the header. I want to show the header inside this div `<div class="box-tools pull-right">`

Can i do that?

Here is my code :

```
<div class="box box-success">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">User Vacation</h3>
              <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div><!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body no-padding">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div class="pad">
                    <!-- Map will be created here -->
                    <div id="world-map-markers">

                        <?php

                            Modal::begin([
                                        'id' => "modifyEvent",
                                        'size' => 'modal-lg'
                                ]);

                            echo "<div id='modalContent'> </div>";

                            Modal::end();
                            ?> 

                        <div class='row'>

                         <?= \yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget(array(
                                    'events'=>$model->getVacationDays(),
                                    'options' => [
                                            'id' => 'DashBoardCalendar',
                                            'class' => 'DashboardCalendarClass'
                                    ],
                                    'header' => 'false',
                                    'clientOptions' => [
                                        'firstDay' => '1',
                                        'selectable' => true,
                                        'selectHelper' => true,
                                        'editable' => true,
                                        'dayRender' => new JsExpression("function(date, cell) {
                                                            $.get('index.php?r=user-vacation-special-days/get-date', { date: date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')}, function(data){
                                                                cell.addClass(data);
                                                            });    

                                                            }"),
                                        'select' => new JsExpression("function(start, end) {
                                                                   // $('#newEventModal').find('#startDate').val(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                                                                   // $('#newEventModal').find('#endDate').val(end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
                                                                    //$('#newEventModal').find('#user').val('".Yii::$app->user->username ."');
                                                                    $('#modifyEvent').modal('show').find('#modalContent').load('index.php?r=user-vacation-days/create-with-attributes&start='+start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')+'&end='+end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));                        
                                                                   // $('#newEventModal').modal('show');

                                                            }"),
                                        'eventDrop' => new JsExpression("function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
                                            $.get('index.php?r=user-vacation-days/update-partion', { id: event.id , start : event.start.format(), end : event.end.format()}, function(data){

                                            });


                                        }"),
                                        'eventResize' => new JsExpression("function(event, delta, revertFunc) {

                                            $.get('index.php?r=user-vacation-days/update-partion', { id: event.id , start : event.start.format(), end : event.end.format()}, function(data){

                                            });

                                        }"),
                                        'eventClick' => new JsExpression("function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                                                                        $('#modifyEvent').modal('show').find('#modalContent').load('index.php?r=user-vacation-days/update&id='+calEvent.id);

                                                                    }"),
                                        'defaultDate' =>  date('Y-m-d') //"2015-04-01"
                                  ],
                      ));?>


                        </div>  



                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div><!-- /.col -->
                <div class="col-md-4 calendarBoxRight">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-11 bg-green">
                            <div class="description-block margin-bottom">
                                <div class="sparkbar pad" data-color="#fff">90,70,90,70,75,80,70</div>
                                <h5 class="description-header">8390</h5>
                                <span class="description-text">Visits</span>
                            </div><!-- /.description-block -->

                            <div class="description-block margin-bottom">
                                <div class="sparkbar pad" data-color="#fff">90,70,90,70,75,80,70</div>
                                <h5 class="description-header">8390</h5>
                                <span class="description-text">Visits</span>
                            </div><!-- /.description-block -->

                            <div class="description-block margin-bottom">
                                <div class="sparkbar pad" data-color="#fff">90,70,90,70,75,80,70</div>
                                <h5 class="description-header">8390</h5>
                                <span class="description-text">Visits</span>
                            </div><!-- /.description-block -->

                            <div class="description-block margin-bottom">
                                <div class="sparkbar pad" data-color="#fff">90,70,90,70,75,80,70</div>
                                <h5 class="description-header">8390</h5>
                                <span class="description-text">Visits</span>
                            </div><!-- /.description-block -->


                        </div>

                    </div>


                </div><!-- /.col -->
              </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div><!-- /.box-body -->
          </div><!-- /.box -->
```

Comment: Yii doesn't stop you from changing html order or div nesting.

Comment: Yep, but can i somehow define where i want to render the calendar header, or i have to make jquery to mask it elsewhere?

Comment: The yii extension does not manipulate views, best approach would be to redefine your view using the given mechanism in fullcalender , see 2nd headline [here](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/) .  You will probably need to extend the yii2fullcalender class to use the updated view.